# Every proper subspace of a normed linear space is either dense or nowhere dense.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> > Every proper subspace of a normed linear space is either dense or nowhere dense.

Our instructor proved this theorem in our class. I have understood each and every step of the proof. But still I have a confusion. Confusion arose due the following example $:$

Consider the real line $\Bbb R$ with the Euclidean norm. Consider the proper subspace $A=[-1,1] \cap \Bbb Q$ then this is neither dense nor nowhere dense. But if the example is true that would definitely violate the above theorem. What's going wrong here? Inspite of my effort I couldn't find out why is it happening. Please help me in this regard.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Subspace in this context is a linear subspace. Your set $A$ is not  a vector space.

Comment: Yeah I have understood sir. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Sorry but does the proof rely on the fact that an open ball generates the whole space? My thinking is if a proper subspace is neither dense nor nowhere dense, then the interior of its closure generates the whole space, which is a subspace of the closure, and so the closure must be the whole space. The set is then dense. Contradiction.